# Opencv draws numpy.zeros as a gray image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm struggling with understanding how opencv interprets numpy arrays.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = (w, h, channels) = (100, 100, 1)
    img = np.zeros(size, np.int8)
    cv2.imshow('result', img), cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Grayscale black 100x100 image, right?
No, it's showing me gray! Why's that?

Answer (score 13):

Ok, the crucial part is dtype. I've chosen `np.int8`. When I use `np.uint8`, it is black.

Suprisingly, when `dtype=np.int8`, zeros are interpreted as 127(or 128)!

I expected that zero is still zero, no matter if it is signed or unsigned.

Comment: If zero in `int8` was black, how would you represent white?

Comment: @ffriend I thought that uint8(-1) = 255. Seems like opencv doesn't do any type casting and interprets signed and unsigned integers differently.

Comment: Recall that any number is just an array of bits, and data type shows us how to interpret this array. OpenCV also sees just bit arrays and uses dtype information to interpret an image. When it sees `uint8` it thinks it's grayscale image with gray levels from 0 to 127 (from lowest to highest possible value). When OpenCV sees `int8`, it interprets the image as grayscale with gray levels from -128 to 127 (again, from lowest to highest). Pixels in floating point image normally have values between 0 and 1. So, dtype is just a way to interpret a bit array, and OpenCV does it in quite intuitive way ;)

Comment: It would've been more intuitive, if it always typecased to uint8, since `np.uint8(np.array([-1], np.int8)) == array([255], dtype=uint8)`. My intuition tells that 0 is a black pixel (no light), 255 is a white pixel (max light). A negative light doesn't make sense to me, so it should be typecasted to unsigned (or produce an error). Floating point interpretation is irrelavant, since we are talking abount signed vs unsigned problem here. How would you treat "-0.5" color? Following your intuition, if the type is `int32`, a zero should be also gray, but it's not! In fact, `uint32` produce an error.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that `imshow` uses particular rules to interpret matrices of particular data types, and these rules are quite independent from each other. If you had only `int8` and no `unit8`, how would you interpret values in it? For me it's quite intuitive to use minimal value (-128) as black and maximal value (+127) as white, though you may disagree with me. Anyway, this is how it is implemented. Note, however, that this is specific to OpenCV. In PIL or Matplotlib, for example, zeros of `uint8`, `int8` and `float32` will all be interpreted as black.

Comment: Exactly. That's the way it is. It is just not a typical interpretation when zero is taken to be black, and 255 is taken to be white.

Answer (score 4):

For a BGR image,

```
img = np.zeros([height, width, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to change 2 things:

1. `size = (w, h, channels) = (100, 100, 3)`

since (100, 100, 1) will create a grayscale image, color images (BGR or RGB) require 3 channels, 1 each for Red, Blue and Green

2. `img = np.zeros(size, np.uint8)`
   (int8 will not be able to capture values from 0-255)